# How To Remove Spaces Between Characters In PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.5, trim

I want to match two tables based on a specific column which is a card number, there are spaces between characters in some of card numbers in the second table like below:

```
'NES 123_4_5'
'MTS 678_9_0'
```

What i want is to remove the space between the characters and numbers and change it to following form:

```
'NES123_4_5'
'MTS678_9_0'
```

What would be the SQL query of function to do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

simplest way - use REPLACE function

```
select REPLACE('NES 123_4_5', ' ', '')
Result - NES123_4_5
```

full list of string functions - https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/functions-string.html

Comment: If we want to do this for an entire column we can update the column:

    update TableName set ColumnName = REPLACE (ColumnName,'  ','');

Comment: Yes of course if You need update column - You update using this function, but if for any reason You must leave column in original state You can use functions in SELECT

Answer (score 2):

If you want to replace **all** spaces, use `replace()`

```
replace('NES 123_4_5', ' ', '')
```

If you only want to replace the space after the first three characters, you can use `regexp_replace()`

```
regexp_replace('NES 123_4_5', '(^[A-Z]{3})( )', '\1')
```

The regular expression will look for there (uppercase) characters at the beginning followed by a single space and will remove that space